# Hide Applications from other Spaces in Application Switcher

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control, application-switcher

With System Preferences->Mission Control->"When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application" disabled, I would really like the application switcher (cmd+tab) to hide applications from other spaces.

Is this possible in Mavericks or is there a third-party application that provides this? Note, I would prefer the application switcher to remain as it is, just hide the applications only active on other spaces.

Comment: So to understand you clear - On a certain Space You will make Cmd + Tab Act like a Rotator over the Apps open only on this screen? Is that what you are looking for? If so thats also what i am looking for. Haven't found something usefull yet.

Comment: I was about to recommend **Witch**, but a quick check reveals that it doesn't *seem* to have that functionality...

Comment: @Alex are you speaking from experience? because on the fourth screenshot on the store page there is a checbox visible saying "list windows from all spaces"

Comment: @dennismuys Oh, you are totally right! Yes, I did check Witch's preferences, but I completely missed that option! Sorry... Well, in that case, Witch works for the OP.

Comment: haha no problem, it is easy to miss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windowflow](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/windowflow/id414445104?mt=12) - free for a limited time and gives some options for different spaces and such.

[Witch](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/witch/id412485838?mt=12) - 12,99 € and has an option that will only show apps in the current space.

[WindowSwitcher](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/windowswitcher/id509502240?mt=12) - 3,59 € and it comes very close to your needs, check it out.

As far as an native solution to your problem: I don't think there is a setting or command that makes the application switcher behave like this.

Definitely check out WindowSwitcher I honestly think it is what you are looking for!

p.s. prices were correct at the time of posting.

Comment: @mtsr is this what you are looking for?
Or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would still be interested in a native solution, but it doesn't seem to be available at the time.

Answer (score -1):

In my application Command-Tab Plus for this function is responsible for this option in the settings

[image: Command-Tab Plus Settings]