# Is there an app other than Witch that allows windows switching (not app switching) with cmd+tab?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager, application-switcher

I found the Witch app (http://manytricks.com/witch/). Are there any other solutions?

Comment: not really what you need but in this thread:http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123924/71490
similar programs are mentioned

Answer (score 7):

[Contexts](https://contexts.co/) looks nice, but I've never used it personally.  It seems to be similar in functionality with Witch, but it has a more modern (iOS 7-style) design.

It does have the ability to map itself to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

It costs $9.

Comment: Thanks. This one's nice. App switching is completely gone though, which would still be nice to have too.

Comment: I tried Witch but the behaviour was totally unexpected. This one is works exactly how you would expect. If you used Vista Switcher on Windows, this app is a clear replacement. It's also much snappier it has a 30 days trial.

Comment: I've been having trouble with Contexts (which I used and loved for years) on Catalina. Just got Witch, and I configured it to get the same behavior using Witch (as in: hit ctrl+space, type/search for window, hit enter).

Comment: This is much better (and faster to show up) than Witch.